# What is `path.home` variable and how do I set it?

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, elastic4s

I have been using the [`elastic4s`](https://github.com/sksamuel/elastic4s) [`elasticsearch`](https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch) driver.

When attempting to create a client:

```
import com.sksamuel.elastic4s._
import org.elasticsearch.common.settings._

val esSettings = //...
val client     = ElasticClient local esSettings
```

I recieve a runtime error:

```
 [IllegalStateException: path.home is not configured]
```

What is `path.home`?
how do I set `path.home`?

Versions: `elasticsearch-2.4.1`, `elastic4s-2.3.1`

Comment: Please don't use different versions of product and api - elastic4s version 2.3.1 meant to work with elasticsearch versions 2.3.X and not 2.4.X

Comment: This is correct and what is mentioned in the `elastic4s` documentation. FYI this error still occurs when using the correct product/api combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What is `path.home`?**

As you can see from the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-dir-layout.html), `path.home` is a variable which must be set to define where on the hard disk to store data.

**How do I set `path.home`?**

After searching/trial and error, I have found that `path.home` **cannot** be set in `elasticsearch.yml` (as indicated in the documentation). This will cause your elasticsearch service to fail when you try load that new config.

`path.home` is a JVM arg.

specifically `-Des.path.home="~/folder/"`

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Rhys' own answer, you can pass path.home into the settings when you create the client.

```
val settings = Settings.builder.put("path.home", "/home/elastic")
val = ElasticClient.local(settings)
```